# How to tell tesseract-OCR to ignore the first half of an image

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I do have image where i am only interested in the area that include the digits inside the circle, how to ignore the first half of the image ? i have tried to use HEADER_HEIGHT but i am fraid that something it might skip some digit , i prefer better solution if you have

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP9im.png)

```
import cv2
import  pytesseract

HEADER_HEIGHT = 400

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/bin/tesseract'


img = cv2.imread('IMG_20230819_163505.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
### Detecting Characters
hImg,wImg,_ = img.shape

cong = r'--oem 3 --psm 5 outputbase digits'
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(img,config=cong)
for x,b in enumerate(boxes.splitlines()):
    if x!=0:
        b = b.split()
        # print(b)
        if len(b)==12:

            x,y,w,h = int(b[6]),int(b[7]) ,int(b[8]),int(b[9])
            if y > HEADER_HEIGHT:
                # Extract digit
                digit = b[11]
                # Print digit and coordinates
                print(f"Digit: {digit}, x: {x}, y: {y}")
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(w+x,h+y),(0,0,255),3)
            cv2.putText(img,b[11], (x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(50,50,255),2)


cv2.namedWindow('Result', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Result',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```